# javascript hasOwnProperty and prototype

Tags: javascript

```
function Animal(name,numLegs){
this.name = name;
this.numLegs = numLegs}

Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name );}

var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
  penguin.sayName();
for (var prop in penguin){
console.log(prop);}
penguin.hasOwnProperty('sayName')
```

### result:

```
name
numLegs
sayName
=> false
```

### I dont know why  hasOwnProperty return false?? can anyone explain?

Answer (score 17):

When JavaScript is looking for a property, it first looks into the object itself. If it isn't there, it normally keeps walking up the prototype chain. `hasOwnProperty` exists to check *only* the object itself, *explicitly not* walking up the prototype chain. If you want to check if a property exists at all, checking everything in the prototype chain, use the `in` operator:

```
'sayName' in penguin  // => true
```

Comment: Just for info, [*propertyIsEnumerable*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.7) doesn't go along the `[[Prototype]]` chain either.

Comment: Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

Because hasOwnProperty check the property is present or not in itself, not as an inherited one form prototypes, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

> This method can be used to determine whether an object has the
>   specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in
>   operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype
>   chain.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'sayname' is inherited from 'Animal' its not 'penguin' own property.

check : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

similar example :

```
function Foo() {
  this.value = 'qwert';
}
Foo.prototype.say = "hello";

var foo = new Foo();

foo.hasOwnProperty("say"); // False, since say is inherited from the prototype object.
foo.hasOwnProperty("value"); // True, since value is the property of foo itself.
```