# hasOwnProperty method in javascript output true?

Tags: javascript

> hasOwnProperty search for __proto__ ?

```
 function Person(){}
 Person.prototype.name = "Nicholas";
 Person.prototype.age = 29;
 Person.prototype.job = "Software Engineer"; 
 Person.prototype.sayName = function(){

 };
 var person1 = new Person();
 person1.hasOwnProperty("name") // false ?
```

> the above example comes from *Prefessional JavaScript for Web Developers*

use chrome :
`person1.hasOwnProperty("name") // is true`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19851511. Seriously google before posting.

Comment: yes, the book show me 'false' ,but chrome show it's 'true'

Comment: @EggVans — No, it shouldn't. It makes no sense to redefine the prototype on a constructor function every time a new instance is created from it.

Comment: sorry .. I mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be true.

`person1.name = "Greg";` gives `person1` its own name property, so it doesn't come via the prototype chain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/19851511. could you mark it as such?

Comment: sorry, rewrite this code now..

Comment: @Lee.zm — After you rewrote the code, chrome returns false.

Comment: sorry, I mistakes ...