# javascript hasOwnProperty prototype and inheritance

Tags: javascript, properties, prototypal-inheritance

I've checked questions:
[javascript what is property in hasOwnProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/javascript-what-is-property-in-hasownproperty)
 and
[javascript hasOwnProperty and prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851511/javascript-hasownproperty-and-prototype)
but couldn't find the answer to my problem. Here is my code:
But some answers are puzzling me (NOT as expected).

```js
function School(schoolName) {
  this.schoolName = schoolName;
}
School.prototype.printSchoolName = function() {
  console.log(this.schoolName);
}

function Student(studentName, schoolName) {
  this.studentName = studentName;
  this.schoolName = schoolName; // alternative : School.call(this, schoolName);
}
Student.prototype = new School(); // force l'héritage des propriétés de School
Student.prototype.printStudentName = function() {
  console.log(this.studentName);
}
var s = new Student("Victor", "IUT");
s.printStudentName(); // works fine
s.printSchoolName(); // works fine
console.log(Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty("printStudentName")); // works as expected: true
console.log(Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty("printSchoolName")); // works as expected: false
console.log(Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty("studentName")); //  NOT as expected: false
console.log(School.prototype.hasOwnProperty("schoolName")); //  NOT as expected: false
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new School())); // schoolName
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Student())); // studentName, schoolName
```

The last 2 alerts don't mention the methods, though these methods have been detected by hasOwnProperty. Puzzling. Thank you.

Comment: Say **what** you expected, what you see instead, and why that isn't what you expect.

Comment: BTW after my failed answer I also see that your inheritance isn't realistic... Student inherits School?

Comment: Why did you expect `Student.prototype` to have an own `studentName` property? And what did you expect its value to be?

Comment: If I say "Not as expected" is when comparing the answer of     console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Student())); // which says [ studentName, schoolName ]  and console.log(Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty("studentName")); which says false for studentName. Can someone explain the behaviour of the two methods, one on the object, the other on the prototype. Why the method printStudentName is a property of the prototype and studentName a property of the object (or something like that).Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that using `new School` to set up `Student.prototype` is an anti-pattern. It's an anti-pattern you see a *lot*, but it's an anti-pattern. (It's also bizarre: `Student` has an "is-a" relationship with `School`?! Normally there'd be a "has-a" relationship [not inheritance], but not an "is-a"...) We'll come back to it.

Answering:

> ```
> console.log(Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty("studentName"));
> //  NOT as expected: false
> ```

Nothing ever sets a `studentName` property on `Student.prototype`, so it's no surprise that it doesn't have the property. The `Student` function will set one on the *instance* when you call it, but `Student.prototype` isn't an instance created by `new Student`, so it's never had one set on it.

Moving on to:

> ```
> console.log(School.prototype.hasOwnProperty("schoolName"));
> //  NOT as expected: false
> ```

Same explanation.

Moving on to:

> ```
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new School()));
> // schoolName
> console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Student()));
> // studentName, schoolName
> ```

The reason you don't see the prototype methods there is because `getOwnPropertyNames` shows only the names of properties directly set on the object you call it on (the new `School` object and the new `Student` object). The methods aren't directly set on those, they're set on the *prototype* of those objects. So they're not listed.

---

Re the anti-pattern: In ES5 and earlier syntax, the correct way to set up prototypical inheritance with constructor functions is via `Object.create`, not calling the constructor. Also, after replacing the object on a function's `prototype` property, it's useful to set its `constructor` property back to what it should be:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(School.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

Of course, in ES2015 (aka "ES6") and later, you can use `class` notation (transpiling if necessary for older browsers), which handles doing it correctly for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your answer is a bit clearer for me. Regarding the "antipattern" scripting, I should confess that I took this snippet from some source on the web, but anyway, I was trying to undestand where I was wrong in expecting something else : I suspected that adding a method to the prototype was simlar to write this.mymethod : function()...

Comment: @allezl'OM: Yeah, I'm afraid you see that all over the place, that's why I wanted to call it out, so you'd know what to do instead. :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe part of the confusion is hasOwnProperty doesn't work as you think for constructor function.
But works as you'd expect for the instance:

```
a = new Student()
a.hasOwnProperty("studentName") //true
```